# Looping through all json elements using Unity Boomlagoon Json

Tags: json

I'm using Boomlagoon Json in my Unity project.  My Json file has several lines in it, and so far I can only get Boomlagoon to read the first one only.  Is there a way I can make a loop where it will go through all parse the entire json file?

Here is my json:

```
{"type": 1, "squads": [{"player_id": 1, "squad": [1, 2, 3, 4]}, {"player_id": 2, "squad": [6, 7, 8, 9]}], "room_number": 1, "alliance_id": 1, "level": 1}
{"type": 2, "squads": [{"player_id": 2, "squad": [1, 2, 3, 4]}, {"player_id": 3, "squad": [6, 7, 8, 9]}], "room_number": 2, "alliance_id": 1, "level": 1}
{"type": 3, "squads": [{"player_id": 3, "squad": [1, 2, 3, 4]}, {"player_id": 4, "squad": [6, 7, 8, 9]}], "room_number": 3, "alliance_id": 1, "level": 1}
```

And when I do a loop like this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JSONValue> pair in emptyObject) { ... }
```

it only gives me results for the first entry (in this example type:1).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your file actually contains 3 JSON objects, and what happens when you parse it is that the parsing stops once the first object ends. You need to parse each line separately to get all of the data.

As an aside, you'll notice that if you paste your JSON into the validator at [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) it'll give you a parsing error where the second object begins.